# Sum of calculated field

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, mysql-error-1054

I have two tables:

- table1 (a,b,c)
- table2 (a,d,f)

I want to get for each b to get sum of multiplication of corresponding d and f

#### table 1 data

```
a   b      c
-------------
1   hello  3
2   bye    4
```

#### table 2 data

```
a  d  f
--------
1  5  3
1  2  4
2  1  3
2  2  3
```

result: hello:5*3+2*4  , bye:1*3+2*3
My query is:

```
  SELECT t1.a, 
         t2.d * t2.f AS m, 
         SUM(m)   
    FROM table1 AS t1, 
         table2 AS t2 
   WHERE t1.a = t2.a 
GROUP BY t1.b
```

So what is wrong here?  In mysql I get #1054 - Unknown column 'm' in 'field list'

Comment: you can't use alias you've soon created. You need to repeat your formula.

Comment: what do you mean by repeating the formula

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT t1.a, t2.d*t2.f AS m, SUM(t2.d*t2.f)
FROM table1 AS t1, table2 AS t2 
WHERE t1.a=t2.a GROUP BY t1.b
```

(I.e. expand the alias)

Answer (score 5):

You can't refer to a column alias in the same SELECT clause - you either need to reproduce the formula:

```
  SELECT t1.a, 
         t2.d * t2.f AS m, 
         SUM(t2.d * t2.f)   
    FROM table1 AS t1 
    JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.a = t2.a 
GROUP BY t1.b
```

..or use a derived table/inline view:

```
SELECT x.a,
       x.m, 
       SUM(x.m)
  FROM (SELECT t1.a, 
               t2.d * t2.f AS m
          FROM table1 AS t1 
          JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.a = t2.a 
      GROUP BY t1.b) x
```

The earliest MySQL allows referring to column aliases is the `GROUP BY` clause (`HAVING` and `ORDER BY` also support column aliases).  But most other databases only support as early as the `ORDER BY` clause.